# When and where did the Allies use starvation tactics in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, military, starvation

There's a [paper](https://cjil.uchicago.edu/print-archive/siege-starvation-war-crime-societal-torture) that claims in relation to the Nuremberg trials:

> The American‑run tribunal hearing the case affirmed the legal “propriety of attempting to reduce [a place controlled by the enemy to] starvation,” holding that “the cutting off of every source of sustenance from without” in such a context was fully compatible with existing international law. It was a tactic the Allies had used themselves.

There's [citation](https://academic.oup.com/book/39838/chapter-abstract/339987180?redirectedFrom=fulltext) for the last fact, but not easily accessible to me right now. So, what are some examples where the Allies used starvation as a tactic in WW2?

Comment: https://www.nationalww2museum.org/war/articles/pacific-strategy-1941-1944 suggests it was in the Pacific, but not terribly specific.

Comment: Certainly a number of Japanese-held islands in the Pacific were bypassed in the island hopping campaign. It was not considered to be worthwhile to assault the islands rather than let them be.

Comment: @JonCuster - That of course wasn't as much a starvation tactic as it was a matter of conservation of their own military forces. Sort of the naval equivalent of an armored breakthrough, cutting supplies to the enemy forces bypassed. Its *possible* starvation ensued, but that depended on the local resources available on the island (one thing tropical places can be great at is growing food). The US didn't much care either way.

Comment: @T.E.D. - well, yes, but leaving the garrisons to 'wither on the vine' could be equated by some authors to using starvation as a tactic. With supply lines cut, starvation certainly did play out for many (most?) such isolated garrisons. Of course, they could have surrendered in theory - practice as you know was quite different for the Japanese.

Comment: I don't know if you will find clear cases between what the the besiegers wanted and what actually happened. Point in case are the [Atlantic pockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_pockets): some were left alone, in some food was let in, in some a civilian evacuation deal was achieved, in some cases supplies could not be blocked, and in the case of Royan, civilians were left inside the pocket and died en masse during the final bombardment. Was starvation a strategy? Against the garrisons, most certainly. Against civilians, maybe it was accepted. Was it achieved? Mostly no.

Comment: Are you asking about doing that to the garrison of an enemy strongpoint?  Or about the garrison *and* a co-located civilian population?  Even now, I doubt the laws of war forbid starving out an *exclusively military* enemy force and wouldn't expect you to *feed* them.  Also, is "Allies" here meant to be Western nations only?  Or does that include Russia?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: any of those. I'm curious how far that went to justify the "Allies did it too" claim.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - at least in the Pacific, there were co-located populations on the islands. Of course, they suffered under Japanese occupation, and invasions of the islands would not have helped them out much either. But claiming intentional starvation would be hard to justify.

Comment: I know you said "Allies" but let's not forget an entire Axis campaign (Atlantic) devoted to cutting supply, including food,  to Britain.

Comment: And had there been no atomic bombs and no invasion of the Japanese home islands, a full, complete, and lengthy blockade by the Allied navies would have the potential of creating mass starvation of the Japanese population . . . who were already on reduced rations.

Comment: In Europe both sides used naval blockades in which food supplies were as much a taget as anything else.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by starvation not physical dying out from hunger, but “the cutting off of every source of sustenance from without”, as you are citing, then the whole strategy and politics of WWII from the side of the Allies included it as one of the main components. The whole Axis side had to be not only beaten down but starved economically too, and it was both beaten and starved.

As for lesser, local operations based on starving, the greatest and the most famous of them was [the Battle of Stalingrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Stalingrad) , more precisely, the 4th and 6th stages of the battle. I mean the following stages:

- Axis attack (dynamic)
- Standing at the shore and in the city (static)
- Soviet Army surrounding the Paulus's army and several lesser troops (German, Italian, Croatian) (dynamic)
- A period of starving out the Axis forces, the aerial bridge attempt, Mannstein's and Paulus's attempts to open the surrounding (static/dynamic)
- Division of the surrounded troop in two. (static/dynamic)
- Final starving out (static)
- the surrender

If you are interested in the strategies, politics, propaganda, and tactics for isolation and suppression of attempts to save the surrounded troops, pay attention to the 4th stage. The 6th one was already trivial, for Hitler could not really help at that stage.

The description of the battle in the wiki article is very abundant. I hope, it will be enough.

AFAIK, the latter strategic surroundings (there were many of them in years 43-45) did not go on for so long, and starvation was not so important part in them.

If we recall the black humour cases of the Japan troops or even persons that were isolated and lost in jungles and surrendered in late forties, fifties, and even in sixties, it is obvious, that starvation as the only instrument does not work. That "beating down" component is imminent.

Every time after 1942 when the USSR started an attack or waited for an attack, a special partisan starving operation began. Partisans, ordered by the head staff, started to sabotage the railways. As the railways were the only powerful and used mean of logistics (roads were too bad, and rivers were not used), the Axis troops had great problems getting munition, spare parts, fresh manpower, etc, every time they needed it the most.

Comment: @justCal Allies: USSR, USA, GB, Canada, Australia, New Zealand. Axis: Germany, Japan, Italy, Romania, Croatia, Hungary, Slovakia. Allies put Axis to starvation. Both in the whole war and at Stalingrad. Where do you see the contradiction with the question? Maybe, I made a mistake or caused a misunderstanding because of my English?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at American side, not considering the overall blockade of the Axis powers, there have been several starvation of military forces, which included fighting elements as well as supporting ones: This was the case particularly against Japanese forces isolated in several locations:

- Islands in the Solomons
- Northern coast of New Guinea
- Rabaul
- And for the Commonwealth side, Burma

Comment: These by-passed garrisons and outposts were not so much blockaded as simply left behind and on their own, sometimes even in the face of continued air attack from nearby allied holdings.  The closer the Allies came to the Japanese center of gravity the less likely there would be any succor from their own forces.